# Module for Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I am facing a new project that will be probably made with sails.js. Is there any way to write 'modules' for Sails, so I can isolate specific views, controllers, models, services, etc. in a module (folder) I can add or remove easily? If not, any idea / hack to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As we all know sails.js is built over node.js and express.js. We can write modules for node.js and then include them in our sails projects.. 
[Here](http://quickleft.com/blog/creating-and-publishing-a-node-js-module) is a beautiful tutorial on how to write and publish node modules..